# Какие JS-библиотеки реализующие графики бесплатны и доступны для коммерческого использования?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, opensource, лицензирование

Я совсем запутался. В данный момент использую ChartJS, но функционала катастрофически не хватает. amCharts и CanvasJS предлагают купить себя за довольно большие деньги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень удобная библиотека **highcharts**. Она бесплатна для некоммерческого использования, но лицензия стоит [не мало](https://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts).

Если вы хотите полностью бесплатный продукт, то смотрите в сторону [D3.js](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) проектов ([пример1](http://c3js.org/), [пример2](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), [пример3](http://dimplejs.org/)). Графики реализованные на D3 как правило *хипстерские*, но под конкретную задачу, что нибудь найти можно. Плюс к этому их достаточно легко самостоятельно кастомизировать и допиливать.